# Lists all characters on keyboard

Tags: assembly, keyboard, character

I am writing a small Assembly OS and i want it to display all the keyboard characters.

Like this.

A B C D (and so) 1 2 3 (and so on)

All of those. I do not know what that is called and I cannot seem to find what it is called on Google. Any help would be nice, code or not. Whatever that is called would be nice as well.

Thank you

Example...

`A B C D E ........ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ..... ! @ # $ % ^`

Comment: Are you looking for "scan code"?

Comment: Or are you looking for "ASCII"?

Comment: @MrLister I am looking for ASCII

Comment: Are you looking for all characters present on a _specific_ keyboard or do you just want to print A-Z, 0-9 and some random undefined set of symbols? Or maybe you want to show all ASCII codes 0-255?

Answer (score 0):

```
    mov ax,0B800h ; segment of textscreen
    mov es,ax
    mov al,"A"
    xor di,di     ; target offset(upper left corner)
    mov cx,3Fh    ; counter
    cld           ; clear direction flag
P1: stosb         ; write ASCII in AL to ES:DI + increase DI
    add di,3      ; step over Attribute byte and let a space between the ASCIIs
    inc al        ; next ASCII
    dec cx        ; decrease counter
    jnz P1        ; jump if zero flag is not set
```